# yii2:why my calender changed to Gregorian after upload?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-user, yii2-extension

```
 $time = Yii::t('user', '{0, date, MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm}', [$model->date]);
```

in my localhost $time is persian (jalali)
and after upload $time is english(Gregorian )

how can i change my $time to jalali (perisan)????

Comment: You use windows or linux?

Comment: My localhost windows and my server is linux

Comment: try to dump Yii::$app in both to check the locale. My guess it will be that locale is set to English in one case and persian in the other.

Comment: check your date.timezone in php.init

Comment: your timezone needs to be looked at , check it in the `php.ini` file on your live server

Answer (score 3):

You should set the timestamp property time_zone as shown bellow:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
```

Another way you can use this function to convert Gregorian to Persian after upload:

```
public function gregorianToPersian($gregorian)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
    $gregorian = date_parse($gregorian);
    $persian = $this->fromGregorian([$gregorian['year'], $gregorian['month'], 
    $gregorian['day'], $gregorian['hour'], $gregorian['minute'], 
    $gregorian['second']])->toPersian('en')->asDateTime();
    return $persian;
}
```